# Why is my h:message for a specific id not displaying correctly in my dynamic form? More in description

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a form which the user can dynamically add and remove a set of form fields (first name, last name, and email) from the form. That part is working fine, but of course I need some validation on those fields, and if I submit the form with just the first set of fields it works great, and I get validation on each field. Once I add the next set of fields and submit I get validation messages on the first set and only one field of the second. I am not really sure what is going on, but here is how `.xhtml` file looks:

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat var="i" value="#{bean.list}">
        <h:panelGrid columns="5" rowClasses="newRoow">
             <h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{i.first_name}"
             required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter a First Name" />
             <h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{i.first_name}"
             required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter a LastName" />
             <h:inputText id="email" value="#{i.first_name}"
             required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter an Email Address"> />
             <h:commandButton value="+">
                 <f:ajax event="click" render="@form" 
                 listener="#{bean.addItemFromList}" />
             </h:commandButton>
             <h:commandButton value="-">
                 <f:ajax event="click" render="@form" 
                 listener="#{bean.removeItemFromList(i)}" />             
             </h:commandButton>

             <h:message for="firstName" errorClass="warnings" showSummary="true" />
             <h:message for="lastName" errorClass="warnings" showSummary="true" />
             <h:message for="email" errorClass="warnings" showSummary="true" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:repeat>

    <h:commandButton value="Submit"
    actionListener="#{bean.someFunction}"
    action="nextPage" />
</h:form>
```

Any ideas as to why this would be failing?

With the first field set it is working great as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6mOv.png The validation is below each field.

With the second and following field sets it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZDHt.png or a bit different because it seems to validate one more field every time I press the add button.

Comment: Note you're doing an iteration and giving same id's to the components. That obviusly will create you problems as you have repeated identifiers in your page.

Comment: I thought that was it too, but I'm pretty sure JSF adds an identifier in the way of an index to the id right before the programmer defined id like `0:myID` and the next iteration would be `1:myID`.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version are you using? Then I will try to reproduce this.

Comment: JSF 2.0, tomcat 7, richfaces 4

Comment: @BalusC could you let me know if you were able to reproduce it?

Comment: I didn't see your comment reply because I wasn't notified. Well, "JSF 2.0" is the JSF specificaiton version. I was asking for the implementation (as of now there are only two major ones: Mojarra and MyFaces) and then its specific version. E.g. "Mojarra 2.1.17".

Comment: It definitely is Mojarra 2.1.12.

Comment: Please use `@nickname` to trigger comment reply nofitications whenever more than 2 users have commented on your post. I did again not see your comment reply. Well, it might be related to one of `<ui:repeat>` issues which are fixed since 2.1.14. Give it a try. It's currently already at 2.1.17. I can't reproduce it with 2.1.17.

Comment: @BalusC do you know if there are many backward compatibility issues by upgrading?

Comment: No, there should be no regressions in 2.1.17.

Comment: @BalusC I updated my JSF to Mojarra 2.1.17 and that didn't fix it so I'm stumped 100%.

Comment: Seeing some bean code would be helpful. I assumed the bean to be in the view scope as that's the most sensible choice for this construct. I also assumed that your getters/setters are all free of business logic.

Comment: @BalusC my bean is `@ViewScoped`, I generated my getters/setters from eclipse and have not touched them, and the add and remove are simple called to `.add` and `.remove` of an array list which is the value of my `<ui:repeat>`.

Comment: Well, is this `<ui:repeat>` nested in another one? In any case ... posting an SSCCE which reproduces exactly the same problem for you in a completely blank playground project with everything set to default would be helpful.

Comment: @BalusC thank you for your help. The `<ui:repeat>` is only inside a `<rich:panel>` which is inside a `<ui:define>`. I may do that tomorrow, but today I have spent entirely too much time on this issues and I need to get to work on some other issues before the day ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later figured out that this wasn't a problem with the code/markup I had written for this problem, but instead from a `.js` file that was included. This `.js` had some code in it that was messing with all elements with a `class="warnings"` which is generated from the `<h:messages />` tags.

Answer (score 0):

here both the components in the same form while submitting the entire form will be submitted so you will get  validation error message.